# Updating UI from Emitter.Listener

Tags: android, socket.io

I'm trying to use SocketIO in my Android app to communicate with the server.

Here's my code:

```
socket = IO.socket("server-address");
            socket.connect();
            socket.on("init", new Emitter.Listener()
            {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args)
                {
                    handleResult(args[0].toString());
                }
            });
```

I'm unable to update the UI from the call function since it is running in the same thread as the UI (my understanding of the issue).

I've tried using an AsyncTask as well but it moves onto doInBackground before the "call" has completed.

How do I update the UI from within this call function? Or how do I send some data out of it?

Comment: Use `Handler`. `call(Object... args)` will be call on background thread .So need to pass the callback to UI thread .

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change UI elements from a `non-UI thread`. Use `runOnUiThread` to Update UI.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // Updat UI here
    }
});
```

Another way to update UI is to Use **Handler**.

```
private void updateUI(final String stringData) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // Updat UI here
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I knew that already but your answer pointed me in the right direction. I simply call the handleResult function inside the runOnUiThread and it works. Didn't realize it was so simple.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach?